# Export Excel with merged cell with hyperlink using Maatwebsite / Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, hyperlink, maatwebsite-excel

I am using **Maatwebsite V3.1** for exporting data as an excel file. I am looping through the data and format them as per excel structure in the *Export Class*. The data structure is like,

```
public function map($user): array {
    return [
               $user->name , $user->ref_title , $user->ref_link
        ];
}
```

I want to merge the **ref_title** and **ref_link** as, in the excel file **ref_title**
text will be a clickable hyperlink of **ref_link**. like, [ref_title](https://ref_link)

I couldn't find any example or documentation regarding mapping hyperlink in **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel v3.1** . Can anyone give me any idea or example without using view (blade file)? I appreciate your help.

Comment: this may help you , https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/926

Comment: I have already gone through the issue. But solutions are based on version 2.x and earlier. I am using v3.1 and Separate Export Class as per v3.1 convention.

Answer (score 5):

Just try to use `registerEvents()` Method, try to add this code :

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                /** @var Worksheet $sheet */
                foreach ($event->sheet->getColumnIterator('H') as $row) {
                    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
                        if ($cell->getValue() != "" && str_contains($cell->getValue(), '://')) {
                            $cell->setHyperlink(new Hyperlink($cell->getValue(), 'Read'));

                            // Upd: Link styling added
                            $event->sheet->getStyle($cell->getCoordinate())->applyFromArray([
                                'font' => [
                                    'color' => ['rgb' => '0000FF'],
                                    'underline' => 'single'
                                ]
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        ];
    }
```

Don't forget to implements `WithEvents` and use `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Hyperlink`

Hope it will helpfull :)

Comment: This solution works perfect.